# Car overheats within 1 mile of driving no traffic

Tags: engine, overheating

1996 Dodge Caravan 3.0 top radiator hose hot and hard bottom hose cold and soft. Did not lose coolant. Temp gauge pegged hot.

Comment: Your thermostat could be stuck closed (or nearly so), or radiator is (at least partially) clogged - something preventing flow.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic signs of a stuck thermostat.

It is stuck in the closed position and causing the engine to overheat.

Replace it ASAP before you blow the head gasket.

Answer (score 0):

The same symptoms would also appear if the car's water pump has failed, or is no longer being driven by its v-belt or serpentine belt.